# Dart/Flutter: change content of container on tab in ListView

Tags: flutter, dart

I am currently trying to create something like a TabBar. I created a horizontal ListView which should work as the TabBar and I my goal is, that one row fills itself with a list that contains the cards for the Tab I clicked on and refreshes when I click on another one. Is there a way to do that? It should look like this:
[Reference Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nTdEl.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you look at [Work with tabs](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/design/tabs), an introduction to `TabBar`, `TabBarView` and `DefaultTabController`?

You could also create it from scratch using a `ListView` with a `Card` wrapped in a `GestureDetector` or a `ListTile`, and detect taps on `onTap`, which would set the selected data and update state using `setState`.

Comment: Thank you! I already looked at the introduction, but unfortunately it doesn't really give me the Design I want, that's why I decided to do it from scratch. My only problem is, that I can't change the cards depending on which tab is selected. I will try again, I am just kinda new to the State management, that's probably why it didn't work. I will post my progress again today. Thank you already!